# aws amplify error 'jsonString' argument missing or empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

1. [terminal log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0GmR.png)

[terminal log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivW4F.png)

2. I am currently using aws-amplify/cli 4.38.0, but when I input the command of the first picture, an error came out, and even if I input the command of the second picture, an error like the picture appears.

Comment: 4.38.0 is just released i.e. approx 21 hours ago. Please try with older version v4.37.1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved it in the following way.

I solved it by amplify delete, amplify init again in the main branch, amplify env add, and then proceed by choosing to not use the existing environment.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when I removed parameters from a file `parameters.json` inside my lambda function. I solved it by adding an empty obj `{}` in my `parameters.json`. Then `amplify push` solved it for me.